# Entity Code First Cyclic Reference Migrations

Tags: ef-code-first, entity, entity-framework-migrations

Thanks in advance! I'm having trouble getting a cyclic reference working where EntityA has a nullable foreign key to EntityB and EntityB has a non-nullable (enforced) reference to EntityA. I've created a sample to demonstrate, but I can't get the migrations to have EntityA's refernce to EntityB to be through a foreign key:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public EntityB MasterEntityB { get; set; }

    public int? MasterEntityBId { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EntityA EntityA { get; set; }

    public int AssociationTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("CyclicTest")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityB>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.EntityA)
            .WithOptional(a => a.MasterEntityB)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

    public DbSet<EntityB> Tenants { get; set; }

    public DbSet<EntityA> AssociationTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the migration I get:

```
    public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.EntityAs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    MasterEntityBId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.EntityBs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    AssociationTypeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.EntityAs", t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Id);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.EntityBs", "Id", "dbo.EntityAs");
        DropIndex("dbo.EntityBs", new[] { "Id" });
        DropTable("dbo.EntityBs");
        DropTable("dbo.EntityAs");
    }
}
```

I can change the migration manually so it's a foreign key like so:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.EntityAs",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(),
                Description = c.String(),
                MasterEntityBId = c.Int(),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.EntityBs", t => t.MasterEntityBId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.EntityBs",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(),
                EntityAId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.EntityAs", t => t.EntityAId)
            .Index(t => t.Id);
```

But then I find I get an error when I insert an EntityB: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EntityB' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Again, appreciate the help!
-Max

Comment: What does the insert statement look like?

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for looking. It's trying to explicitly push in an Id. You'll notice the default transforms didn't think Id on EntityB was an identity, I had to add that manually. It's worked in the DB, but I feel I need to tell the DataContext this. I tried using the attribute but no good [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
SQL:   
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[EntityBs]([Id], [Name], [EntityAId])
VALUES (@0, NULL, @1)
',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=0

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem. I didn't have a reference for the one to many from A to B via a virtual Collection. That was enough to solve the problem. Plus I've decided to use a sub class for the Master Reference so I don't need a second reference from B back to A for the master instance. That would be null for all other instances and could lead to duplicates breaking the 0 or 1 to 1 intended relationship between MasterB and A. I.e.:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    **public ICollection<EntityB> EntityBs { get; set; }**

    public MasterEntityB MasterEntityB { get; set; }

    public int? MasterEntityBId { get; set; }
}

public class MasterEntityB : EntityB
{
}

public class EntityB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public EntityA EntityA { get; set; }

    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
}
```